# How do I create a SHA1 hash in ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash, sha1

[SHA Hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1)

Comment: SHA-1 is has been shown to be insecure. Consider using safer alternatives, such as SHA-256, or SHA-3. https://shattered.io/

Answer (score 398, accepted):

```
require 'digest/sha1'
Digest::SHA1.hexdigest 'foo'
```

Comment: There's also `Digest::SHA1.base64digest 'foo'`

Comment: FYI: `Digest` is part of the Ruby Standard Library (http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/digest/rdoc/index.html).  It includes implementations for SHA1, SHA2, MD5 and others hash algorithms.

Comment: FYI, you should use `Digest::SHA2.hexdigest` now as it is more secure and has not (yet) been found to have any collisions.

Answer (score 8):

For a Base64 encoded hash, to validated an Oauth signature, I used

```
require 'base64'
require 'hmac-sha1'

Base64.encode64((HMAC::SHA1.new('key') << 'base').digest).strip
```

Comment: FYI, the 'hmac-sha1' requirement is met from the gem 'ruby-hmac'

Answer (score 7):

I created a helper [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/rickshaw) which is a simple wrapper around some sha1 code

```
require 'rickshaw'
> Rickshaw::SHA1.hash('LICENSE.txt')

 => "4659d94e7082a65ca39e7b6725094f08a413250a" 

> "hello world".to_sha1

 => "2aae6c35c94fcfb415dbe95f408b9ce91ee846ed"
```

Answer (score -24):

Where 'serialize' is some user function defined elsewhere.

```
 def generateKey(data)
    return Digest::SHA1.hexdigest ("#{serialize(data)}")
 end
```

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of @devstopfix's answer?

Comment: even if it is, it's some pretty ugly ruby code to be suggesting, and doesn't even mention that it needs `require \'digest/sha1\'' -1

Comment: Don't forget that stackoverflow has too many visitors, why you don't show us the right way to do it? Less critics more code examples

Comment: what's this 'serialize' function? that's not a part of ruby. Worse yet, the string being passed to hexdigest isn't dynamic at all! This method would return the same hash regardless what data you give it!

Comment: Need `require 'digest/sha1'` in order to use `SHA1` method.