# SHA1 hashing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sha1

I have database with following fields: `id`, `q_id`, `text`, `session` etc. and I have already 2 records there. I want to hash each line with SHA1 alghoritm (every line is unique of course). I tried this:

```
@w = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(id+q_id+text+session)
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: 1) SHA1 is for hashing, not for encryption. Check, e.g., Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) to read up on basics. 2) What *exactly* isn't working?

Comment: SHA-1 is has been shown to be insecure. Consider using safer alternatives, such as SHA-256, or SHA-3. https://shattered.io/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

SHA is not encryption but rather it creates a [cryptographic hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). If that is still what you want to do, my guess is that `id` and `q_id` are Fixnums and needs to be converted to strings.

```
@w = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(ans.id.to_s + ans.q_id.to_s + ans.text + ans.session)
```

I also kind of like to use String literals because it makes it very obvious that we are dealing with a string

```
@w = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("#{id}#{q_id}#{text}#{session}")
```

Comment: See How do I create a SHA1 hash in ruby?(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34490/how-do-i-create-a-sha1-hash-in-ruby)